# Delete record from SQL database in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to delete a record which is related to the `SerialNo` in the database.

This is my code:

```
Using con = New MySqlConnection("server=" & server & ";" & "user id=" & userid & ";" & "password=" & password & ";" & "database=" & database)
    con.Open()
    Dim sqlText = "DELETE * FROM datatable WHERE SerialNo = @ulogin"
    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlText, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ulogin", frmmain.txtinput.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    con.Close()
End Using
```

This code doesn't work. When I run the program, the following error appears:

[image]

Please be kind enough to suggest a suitable solution.

**NOTE:** 221 means the entered number.

Comment: Remove the * it's not needed in the [DELETE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189835.aspx) statement

Comment: I tested the code without * also @Jinx88909 But it doesn't working.

Comment: The datatype is INT. Then what must I do? @Plutonix

Comment: That would provide a different error. The error in your question is relevant to the * and is not valid syntax. As for the `DataType`, I would explicitly set it like so `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ulogin", SqlDbType.Int).Value =`

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)  Note that `ExecuteNonQuery` is a function telling you how many rows were affected: `Dim rows = ExecuteNonQuery()` is the place to start.  If it is non zero something **was** deleted

Comment: use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ulogin", CInt(frmmain.txtinput.Text))`... convert that `txtinput.text` to `integer`... of course, made some validation if You enter something other then number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` does not belong. You can't delete only specific columns from a record. You either delete the whole record or do nothing, and so there is no column list portion to a `DELETE` statement.

While I'm here, there's no need to call `con.Close()` (the `Using` block takes care of that for you) and it's better to avoid `AddWithValue()` in favor of an `Add()` overload that lets you be explicit about your parameter type.

```
Const sqlText As String = "DELETE FROM datatable WHERE SerialNo = @ulogin"
Using con As New MySqlConnection("server=" & server & ";" & "user id=" & userid & ";" & "password=" & password & ";" & "database=" & database), _
      cmd AS New MySqlCommand(sqlText, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ulogin", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = frmmain.txtinput.Text
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Comment: +1 I like the use of nested Using statements, makes code much simpler to read. It would be worth doing what Plutonix suggested with Dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery to be in the know if the record actually was deleted.

Comment: @Jinx88909  I started doing this in C#, but honestly I think this VB equivalent might be a bug. The `,` separator likely makes a new statement rather than continuing the `Using` declaration. But I've never had a trouble ticket as a result, and I like the conciseness. It's really the DB connection you need to care about most.

Comment: Thank you so much @JoelCoehoorn and those who came to help me in this problem